# Binding a ComboBox to part of an ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, combobox

I have a WPF application in C# where I have an object of class `MyCollection` that extends `ObservableCollection<MyType>` which holds items for the purpose of binding them to several ComboBoxes.

However, every ComboBox must display a subset of this collection (based on a certain property of its elements), and that may change based on user input.

How can I obtain this behavior keeping every subset updated with data from the original collection? Is there some well known design pattern for this scenario?

---

EDIT: Since my formulation of this question is easily misunderstood, here's an example.
I have an `ObservableCollection<Person>` object, where the class `Person` has an `Age` and `Name` properties.
I have three combo boxes, the first two must display the `Name` of `Person` objects with an odd `Age`, while the third must it of those with an even `Age`. Their roles might change at runtime (e.g. first and last has to display odd ages, the second even ages)
If `Person` objects are added to or deleted from the collection, changes must be reflected on the corresponding ComboBoxes.
`Name` and `Age` properties may be considered constant.

Comment: implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Comment: I don't understand, can you be more specific?
ObservableCollection<T> already implements INotifyPropertyChanged, but that won't solve the issue, while the properties of its elements don't change.
Where should I implement it and how?

Comment: the T object needs to implement INPC or you need to manually hook up an items changed event, or it won't report changes when the T object properties change. i.e. you can have a ObservableCollection<Person> bound to your combo box but you won't see the changes made to individual person in the collection.

Comment: I don't think that is what the OP is asking. If I understand it correctly, the questions is, of a list containing "1, 2, 3" how do you have one combo box have "1" another, "1, 2" and a third "1, 3" and those can change based on user input. The objects inside never change, so it isn't a NotifyPropertyChanged issue.

Comment: What you are saying is true, but it doesn't seem to address my problem. However, now that I read my question twice, I see that I've been a bit imprecise when describing it:
I'm not concerned with changes in the properties of the collection elements, but with changes in the subsets.
I want that when an element is added/deleted to/from the main collection, they get added/deleted even to/from every ComboBox that is displaying the appropriate subset.

EDIT: It is as @LordTakkera says, I shall add some details to the question so that it is possible to understand better.

Comment: @Pharanoise Check out my answer, it does exactly what you are describing, even displaying the new/removed items in the collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you need some sort of filtering mechanism.

Take a look at an `ICollectionView` interface and its implementations such as `CollectionViewSource` that might help you to achieve this.

You need to handle the `Filter` event that implements the filtering logic.

Here is the class at MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource(v=vs.110).aspx)

An example:

Container class:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Capital { get; set; }

public Country(string name, string capital) {
    this.Name = name;
    this.Capital = capital;
}
```

Model class:

```
private ObservableCollection<Country> _countries;
private ICollectionView _european;
private ICollectionView _american;

public ObservableCollection<Country> Countries {
    get {
        if (_countries == null) {
            _countries = new ObservableCollection<Country>();
        }

        return _countries;
    }
}

public ICollectionView European {
    get {
        if (_european == null) {
            _european = new CollectionViewSource {
                Source = this.Countries
            }.View;
            _european.Filter += (e) => {
                Country c = e as Country;
                if (c.Name == "UK" || c.Name == "Ireland" || c.Name == "France") {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            };
        }

        return _european;
    }
}

public ICollectionView American {
    get {
        if (_american == null) {
            _american = new CollectionViewSource {
                Source = this.Countries
            }.View;
            _american.Filter += (e) => {
                Country c = e as Country;
                if (c.Name == "USA" || c.Name == "Canada" || c.Name == "Mexico") {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            };
        }

        return _american;
    }
}
```

Initialization code:

```
private Model _model;

public Model Model {
    get {
        if (_model == null) {
            _model = new Model();
        }

        return _model;
    }
}

public MainWindow() {
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = this.Model;
    this.Model.Countries.Add(new Country("UK", "London"));
    this.Model.Countries.Add(new Country("Ireland", "Dublin"));
    this.Model.Countries.Add(new Country("France", "Paris"));
    this.Model.Countries.Add(new Country("USA", "Washington D. C."));
    this.Model.Countries.Add(new Country("Mexico", "Mexico City"));
    this.Model.Countries.Add(new Country("Canada", "Ottawa"));
}
```

XAML:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ComboBox
        ItemsSource='{Binding Path=European}'>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation='Horizontal'>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text='{Binding Path=Name}' />
                    <TextBlock
                        Text=', ' />
                    <TextBlock
                        Text='{Binding Path=Capital}' />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

    <ComboBox
        ItemsSource='{Binding Path=American}'>
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel
                    Orientation='Horizontal'>
                    <TextBlock
                        Text='{Binding Path=Name}' />
                    <TextBlock
                        Text=', ' />
                    <TextBlock
                        Text='{Binding Path=Capital}' />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: I'm not sure that will work when each combo box needs its own source.

Comment: I can't say if this is what I've been looking for until I read more about it (which I'm about to), but it certainly looks like it goes in that direction. In the meantime, thanks for the answer!

Comment: I am pretty sure it will work. I am working on an example, and hopefully will post it here in a minute.

Comment: It's exactly what I was looking for: to use a single collection as a source and view "synchronized" subsets of it.
I tried your code and it worked as expected.
I am not very familiar with the syntax with which the filter criteria is specified, but I will look for it.
Thanks for the answer!

Comment: @Pharanoise It is just a (delegate) function that returns `true` in case you want to include that item in the subset, and `false` to exclude it. The example uses naive approach.